# How to print error message when user enters anything that is not a double?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Java program that reads a double value from the user, Printing the difference between   these two numbers   so  that the difference is  always  positive. I need to display an Error message if anything other than a number is entered. Please help, thank you !!

When I run the program and enter the second double value nothing happens. I have also tried adding try and catch but I get errors saying num1 cannot be resolved to a variable :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Positive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Reads input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  

        System.out.println ("Please enter a double vaule: ");

            double num1 = Math.abs(sc.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("Please enter a second double vaule: " );
            double num2 = Math.abs(sc.nextDouble());
            double total  = 0;
            double total2 = 0;      

        if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        num1 = sc.nextDouble();

        if (num1>num2) {
            total = ((num1 - num2)); 
            System.out.println("The difference is " + total);
        }   

        if ((num1 < num2)); {
            total2 = ((num2 - num1));
            System.out.println("The difference is "+ total2);
        }

        }else {
            System.out.println("Wrong vaule entered");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if ((num1 < num2)); {` Remove the semicolon between `)` and `{`. Consider `double a = Math.min(num1, num2);` and `double b = Math.max(num1, num2);` - that should allow you to calculate `b - a` consistently.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. You just need to remove the semicolon (`;`) after the last `if` and properly nest your conditions:

```
if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
    num1 = sc.nextDouble();

    if (num1 > num2) {
        total = (num1 - num2); 
        System.out.println("The difference is " + total);
    }   
    else if (num1 < num2) {
        total2 = (num2 - num1);
        System.out.println("The difference is "+ total2);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Wrong vaule entered");
}
```

Comment: I have made these change but when I enter the second double value on the console nothing happens and it doesn't give me the difference:/

Answer (score 0):

To show error message until the user enters a double value I used a `while` loop for each value (`num1` and `num2`).

If user enters a wrong value `"Wrong vaule entered, Please enter again: "` message will show and waits for the next input `sc.next();` 
If user enters a double value `check` will be `false` and exits `while loop`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Positive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Reads input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a double vaule: ");

        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        double total = 0;
        double total2 = 0;
        boolean check = true;

        while (check) {
            if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                num1 = Math.abs(sc.nextDouble());
                check = false;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong vaule entered, Please enter again: ");
                sc.next();
            }
        }
        check = true; // that's for second control
        System.out.println("Please enter a second double vaule: ");
        while (check) {
            if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                num2 = Math.abs(sc.nextDouble());
                check = false;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong vaule entered, Please enter again: ");
                sc.next();
            }
        }
        if (num1 > num2) {
            total = ((num1 - num2));
            System.out.println("The difference is " + total);
        } else if ((num1 < num2)) {
            total2 = ((num2 - num1));
            System.out.println("The difference is " + total2);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add this I get an error saying 'InputMismatchException cannot be resolved to a type. Also, an error saying num1 cannot be resolved to a variable :(

Comment: Do you want to show error message until the user enters a double value? Or just just display error message and exit?

Comment: I want the error message to show until the user enters a double value.

Comment: I changed your code this way, please take a look @Cameron Young

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code and when you enter your first double, type in something random like "abc". What happens? In your console it should display an error named `java.util.InputMismatchException`. You can use a `try` `catch`  block like so:

```
try {
    //tries to get num1 and num2
    double num1 = Math.abs(sc.nextDouble());
    double num2 = Math.abs(sc.nextDouble());
} catch (java.util.InputMismatchException i){
    //will only go here if either num1 or num2 isn't a double
    System.out.println("error");
}
```

Basically, the code will try to get `num1` and `num2`. However if you enter a non-double, it'll "catch" the `java.util.InputMismatchException` and go to the `catch`block

I might've misinterpreted your question, but if you want to find the absolute value of the difference between `num1` and `num2`, all you have to do is:
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter a double value: ");
            double num1 = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter a double value: ");
            double num2 = sc.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("The difference is: " + Math.abs(num1 - num2));

        } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException i) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the try and catch to my version and it displays an error saying num1 cannot be resolved to a variable :(

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Did you make sure you initialized num1 and num2 somewhere?

Comment: I have just gone with your example. Thank you so much!!